# exit a loop when q is entered

Tags: java, loops

i am creating a looped java program that takes two points that the user enters and finds the distance between the points, and exits the loop when the user enters a q. right now i have it so it exits when  a q is entered in but now im getting an error when i enter numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bonus1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Enter the x and y coordinates for point 1: ");
            String x1 = input.nextLine();

            if (quit(x1))
                break;

            double x1_d = Double.parseDouble(x1);
            String y1 = input.nextLine();

            if (quit(y1))
                break;

            double y1_d = Double.parseDouble(y1);

            System.out.print("Enter the x and y coordinates for point 2: ");
            String x2 = input.nextLine();

            if (quit(x2))
                break;

            double x2_d = Double.parseDouble(x2);

            String y2 = input.nextLine();
            if (quit(y2))
                break;

            double y2_d = Double.parseDouble(y2);
            double distance = Math.sqrt(((x2_d - x1_d) *
                                       (x2_d - x1_d) + 
                                       (y2_d - y1_d)*(y2_d - y1_d)));

            System.out.printf("The distance of the two points is: %.2f \n" , distance);
        } 
    } // main()

    public static boolean quit(String input) {
        return input.equalsIgnoreCase("q");
    }
} // Bonus1
```

Comment: If this is part of a homework problem, please label it as such. Also, you are more likely to get the correct answer to your issue if you show what error you are getting and the stack trace for the error.

Comment: Please add the error meesage you are getting.

Comment: I just ran your program and it ran exactly as expected with no errors. What error are you getting?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine, provided you enter the data as you have written the code to parse it - one number then enter, then another number then enter - for each prompt. I suspect you're trying to enter a number followed by a space then another number, which is not what your code is expecting nor can handle.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you better use input.nextDouble() instead of input.nextLine() so that you can directly access the double variable and be sure this is a java program and pthe printf statement can not be used and make it print or println and check syntax...

Comment: The program compiles fine but when i enter in a double value i get "exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFomatException for input sting". it wont read numbers anymore but it does quit when i enter q, but its still no good to me, and yes this is homework.